# Uploading animated GIFs on Facebook

Tags: facebook, animations

I'd like to upload or link to an animated GIF to Facebook in such a way that ideally it would display animated in the profile page.  If that's not possible, it should at least animate when clicked.

As it is, when I upload an animated GIF it gets flattened to a static image, in the profile as well as in the detail view.

I have found tips that say that it needs to be at most 120x120 pixels in size, which doesn't work for me.  Other tips say that the GIF needs to have a "**.jpg**" extension, which also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Facebook compresses/modifies all images, so changing file size or image width will not matter.

The reasons that this were previously possible is because it seems there was a lower set point with which files were unmodified when they were uploaded. (The new minimum width is 180 px)

jpg is just the extension. The header content would still show what the data is supposed to represent when viewed in a browser.

Also although not stated anywhere in the TOS,

> By uploading a file you certify that you have the right to distribute this picture and that it does not violate the [Terms of Service](http://www.facebook.com/terms.php).

Facebook does not allow animations; apps have been shutdown for trying to encourage using animation as pictures.